# Can I be Shi'a while still believing that Allah has blessed the khoulafaa (Omar, Othman, Abou Bakr)?

Tags: shiism, sahaba, khilafah

I found Du'a made by Khomayni (Shi'a) دعاء صنمي قريش asking Allah to take Khoulafaa (Omar, Othman, Abou Bakr) into the eternal hell. I also saw many Shi'a fatwas which say that العشرة المبشرين بالجنة are all in hell except for Ali ibn Abi Taleb.

How many Shi'a agree with Khomayni? Can I be a Shi'a without believing that the three above are in hell, and in general all Sahaba apostate except 4 of them (كتاب سليم بن قيس صفحة162)?

I want an answer according to a Shi'ite perspective.

Comment: This dua is **not** made by Ayatollah Khomeini! It shows up in traditional Shia hadith sources and its authenticity is disputed among Shia scholars. However the Shia belief in unrighteousness and eternal damnation of all caliphs except Ali ibn Abi Talib can not be disputed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the Shi'ite sects including the *Twelvers*, which form majority of them, cannot resolve with the matter. But there are some minorities like Zaidiya who believe in the uprightness of the three Companions or at least do not curse them. Also there are those who call themselves as 'rational Shia' who seem to compromise with the hostility towards the Companions and adopt more liberal view.

Comment: so as I understand the majority of SHIA curse the thee companions??

Comment: All of them actually, they make some exceptions, usually four including Ali (RA). Some even believe that the Sahaba become apostates by giving allegiance to Abu Bakr RA. Zaydiyyah type Shi'ites was the majority and dominant in the early years, but over the time the extremists and Ghullat gained power. But one has to be careful while dealing with them, as there usually are two categories of people in every sect, those who are simply ignorant about these matters and those who can be taken as responsible.

Comment: This answer is not from a Shiite perspective. It is pretty much the Sunni perspective and your comment is also elusive as it is not clear which groups are exactly described as to be 'extremist' and 'ghulat', because by some of the definitions I also personally fall into your categories as I believe in eternal existence of Prophet and His Purified Household Light.